# How to multiply the array elements by itself

Tags: text-processing

I have an array file and I need to do a math operation with the elements. The operation that I need to do is to multiply the element by itself, the to print it.

The input looks like this:

```
1: 6.1703
44 -0.27135
46 0.30270
44 0.52648

2: 6.1932
44 0.51448
46 0.14674
44 0.27957
46 -0.31834

3: 6.5664
45 -0.11892
45 0.66483
46 0.12505
```

the first row of each array is the header. The math operation need to be done with the elements of the second column.

The output need to be:

```
1: 6.1703
44 0.07363
46 0.09162
44 0.27718

2: 6.1932
44 0.26468
46 0.02153
44 0.07815
46 0.10134

3: 6.5664
45 0.0141
45 0.44199
46 0.01563
```

Any ideas or suggestion?

Comment: can't get your math operation...

Comment: @malyy multiplying a number by itself is also called squaring :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `awk` to do this:

```
awk '$1 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ {$2*=$2}; 1'
```

If first column is a number, multiply the second by itself. Then print entire line.

Comment: Hi @milk, what modification I need to do if I want to multiply the squared number by a constant (for example times 2). Other question is what is the utility of ^[0-9] . If you can comment the lines will be greatful!!

Comment: ^[0-9]  - it's regex expression
in general read it like: if row in 1st column contains only number (where 1: doesn't suit) - then do math on the 2nd.
similar espression -  "$1 !~ /:/ " means - if row doesn't contain symbol ":" - do the math.
"multiply the squared number by a constant" - change to {$2*=$2*2};

Answer (score 0):

```
while read line; do                                # for all lines in the file
  i=0                                              # initialise loop counter
  for param in $line; do                           # for all words on the line
    if [[ $i -ne 0 ]]; then                        # if its not the first one
      echo $param | awk '{printf "%4.3f\n",$1*$1}' # print the result of squaring
    fi                                             # (you could output to a file with >>)
    ((i++))                                        # increment loop counter
  done
done < yourfilename                                # stream in your file
```

Comment: HI @Michael  , something not work for your script. The output is only 4.3f

Comment: Related: [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks. I'll have a read.

Comment: @alloppp that's because @Michael missed a `%` before `4.3f`

Comment: I have added the missing `%` in `printf`.